# Can't pass object to managed bean via a p:contextMenu in a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I have a problem with Primefaces data-table and context menu.

Context menu contains only one option, which deletes row with records.

How I understood, I need to pass to managed bean **var parameter** (order)? which contains row data in map structure.

```
<p:dataTable id="#{id}" var="order" rowIndexVar="rowId" value="#{ordersProvider}" emptyMessage="No more rows" rowKey="#{id}" selectionMode="single">
    <p:column headerText="№" filterBy="#{order.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.id}"/>
        </div>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="№ on site" filterBy="#{order.noticeNumber}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div style="text-align: center;">

                <h:outputText value="#{order.noticeNumber}" />
                <f:param name="searchString" value="#{order.noticeNumber}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Company" filterBy="#{order.customerName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.customerName}"/>
        </div>
    </p:column>
    <p:column id="col">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:contextMenu for="#{id}">
                <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="#{id}" icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{clientOrdersBean.cancel(order)}"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here is my bean method, for deleting data.

```
    public void cancel(OrderBG order){

    order.setStatus(OrderStatus.Canceled);
    Environment.getInstance().getServiceProvider().getOrderBgService().save(order);
}
```

The problem is, that value passes - null. I don't know how to get whole row from table.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the PrimeFaces showcase on how to use a contextMenu in dataTable more effectively... Use that in combination with 'selection'. And in the title you talk about a 'Map', but you pass an 'OrderBG'?

Comment: OrderBG - is map (Map data structure) in current context.

Comment: You did not even respond to a big suggestion in the first comment...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was successfully resolved by getters and setters.

In managed bean:

```
private OrderBG newOrder = new OrderBG();

public OrderBG getNewOrder() {
    return newOrder;
}

public void setNewOrder(OrderBG newOrder) {
    this.newOrder = newOrder;
}

public void cancel(){

    getNewOrder().setStatus(OrderStatus.Canceled);
    Environment.getInstance().getServiceProvider().getOrderBgService().save(getNewOrder());
}
```

In xhtml UI:

```
    <p:contextMenu for="#{id}">
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="#{id}" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{clientOrdersBean.cancel}"/>
</p:contextMenu>

<p:dataTable id="#{id}" var="order" value="#{ordersProvider}" emptyMessage="Заявки отсутствуют" rowKey="#{id}" selection="#{clientOrdersBean.newOrder}" selectionMode="single">
```

Comment: So you actually put the context menu outside the datatable as shown in the PrimeFaces showcase... And used selection as done in the PrimeFaces Showcase... Please state a little more what you explicitly did instead of just the code